# Matlab Error in C# Assembly: Undefined function 'mwltelibrary' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, lte

I'm using MATLAB Builder NE to build some MATLAB functions into .NET assembly and invoke them from C#. Then I encountered this error:

-----------------------------------Error-------------------------------

... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ...

Undefined function '**mwltelibrary**' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in => Testfunction.m at line 62.

... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...

at file C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\Owner\mcrCache8.3\Test\toolbox\lte\lte\lteTBS.m, name lteTBS, line 37.

at file C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\Owner\mcrCache8.3\Test\Testfunction.m, name Testfunction, line 62.

-----------------------------------END---------------------------------

In Testfunction.m line 62, that function invokes the function **lteTBS** from lteTBS.m which is provided by MathWork. Actually, this .m file is written by my colleague and I know nothing about Matlab. If I run this function in command window of Matlab (R2014a 32bit in Windows 8.1 pro 64bit), it works.

I have checked that machine and all followed components have been installed.

*MATLAB,
MATLAB Builder NE,
MATLAB Compiler,
Communications System Toolbox,
DSP System Toolbox,
LTE System Toolbox,
Signal Processing Toolbox*

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In fact the only thing you need on the target machine is the MCR (MATLAB Compiler Runtime). Check the `mccExcludedFiles.log` file generated by the MATLAB Compiler to see if your function was included in the deployment to begin with.

Comment: Vache, Thanks. I have checked mccExcludedFiles.log. It's empty.

Comment: Hmm then since the error comes from within a toolbox function I'm afraid I have nothing else to suggest than to ask Mathworks support.

Answer (score 0):

Some Updates:

I have tried to invoke another LTE api and got this error: **LTE System Toolbox does not support the deployed mode**.

I also contacted the MathWorks technical supporter and he said LTE System Toolbox can not be deployed in this way.

Here is my workaround: run MATLAB application with some parameters using System.Diagnostics.Process.

If the MATLAB is not installed in the local machine, it has to send a request to the server with MATLAB installed.

You can find some useful information from this [post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102082-how-do-i-call-matlab-from-the-dos-prompt) in MathWorks forum.